# php print all value for one variable in a href

Tags: php, mysql

How can i print all values of one variable read it from mysql database in a href
in this code below the variable is **$src** and the values are read it from database like below

```
$file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    $src=$r['db_image'];}
    echo"<a href='download.php?src=$src'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
}
```

I want the result in a href be like this when i put the mouse on it

....../download.php?src=xxx.png-yyy.jpg-rrr.jpeg

is that possible and how to do it??!!

Comment: whats ur current result

Comment: what $src contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for implode:

```
<code>
$file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$src = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    $src[]=$r['db_image'];}
}
echo '<a href="download.php?src='.implode('-',$src).'><img src="../img/download.png"></a>';
</code>
```

Comment: i don't think that $src is an array here , it s $src=$r['db_image'] not $src[]=$r['db_image'] like you wrote it

Comment: one can edit $src to array for better result ;). @mr.void answer seems to be legit

Comment: hum ... i don't see how it give better result :/ . he already have the content he want to display, he just want to know how to simply display it, so why change it and make it an array ?

Comment: @mr.void i have this message error Fatal error: Call to undefined function arrray() in

Comment: i solve it without this $src=array();  like this      $file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    $src[]=$r['db_image'];}
    echo"<a href='download.php?src=".implode('-',$src)."'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
}

Comment: @m7md this was just an typo. It should be array not arrray ... Its better to initialize the array. 

If you use it, please mark my answer.

Comment: ...to which I fixed. You should have edited that instead @mr.void

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate your variables

```
echo "<a href='download.php?src=".$src."'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
```

Comment: ok my bad. You should clarify you question so, because looking at the answers,  i m not the only one that hadn't understand the question i think ;)

Comment: i solve it like this from the answer i receive it     i solve it without this $src=array(); like this $file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn)); if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){ while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){ $src[]=$r['db_image'];} echo"<a href='download.php?src=".implode('-',$src)."'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>"; }

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    $src=$r['db_image'];}
    echo "<a href='download.php?src=".$src."'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help:

```
$src='';
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    if(empty($src)){
         $src=$r['db_image'];
    } else {
         $src.= '-'.$r['db_image'];
    }
}
echo"<a href='download.php?src=$src'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
```